# Quantlib-SWIG - how to do a clean rebuild on windows/msvc

Tags: quantlib-swig

I had Quantlib (1.4) and Quantlib-SWIG/Python successfully installed (compiled using MS Visual Studio Express 2013 for quantlib and as per the readme, using `python setup.py build` followed by `python setup.py install`. )

I then wanted to modify some of the SWIG files, and reinstall. I tried `python setup.py clean --all` to get the modified files to be picked up on a subsequent build, but that didn't work.

Under linux it is fine, I just do `make clean` and then reinstall using python setup, but under Windows (where I don't have make installed), I am drawing a blank.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you modified the SWIG files, you need to run `python setup.py wrap` to regenerate the C++ and Python wrappers that you'll compile and install (note that you'll need the SWIG executable `swig.exe` in your `PATH`). After this, running `python setup.py build` and `install` again will give you the updated module.

On linux, the Makefile knows about the additional step and does it for you (in fact, you shouldn't even need to run `make clean`; just running `make` should work, since make will notice that the SWIG files are newer than the wrappers).